# Can a Summoner Cast the Summon Monster Spell With His Eidolon Out?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, summoning, summoner, eidolon

I have [Summon Monster IV](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) on my spell list.  Do I have to dismiss my [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner#TOC-Eidolon) before casting the spell, or can I cast it even with my eidolon out? I remember you couldn't have the eidolon and summon monster conjured by the SLA out at the same time, thus meaning that'd you'd have to dismiss the eidolon before using the SLA. I was wondering if this extends to the ordinary spell as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## You do not have to dismiss your Eidolon to cast Summon Monster.

I can see your confusion, however.  Summoners have a class feature called Summon Monster, which lets them use certain specific *summon monster* spells as spell-like abilities.  When you use those spell-like abilities, you can't also have your Eidolon out.

The Summon Monster class ability says:

> Drawing upon this ability uses up the same power as the summoner uses to call his eidolon. As a result, he can only use this ability when his eidolon is not summoned.
>
> A summoner cannot have more than one *summon monster* or *gate* spell active **in this way** at one time.

Emphasis mine. This restriction only applies to the Summon Monster class feature, not the *summon monster* spell.  There is no restriction against casting *summon monster* while you have your Eidolon out, or even when you have used your Summon Monster spell-like ability.

Answer (score -4):

Don’t treat your spell like abilities like spells. Example, you can have your eidolon out via “summon eidolon” spell and have summon monsters out via your spell like ability. Any DM that tells you otherwise is deceiving you, or nerfing you.

Comment: Hi, 2020. Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange! An important aspect of this site is that answers try to directly answer the question and provide some form of support for the content of the answer. When you have time, I recommend you check out the Help section on [how to write a good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for some guidance :)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.