# Summoners and the summon monster ability and summon eidolon spell

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, summoner

I am a summoner which gives me the ability to have an eidolon and also use an ability to summon monsters. The question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49224/23058) is related but different.

Under [unchained summoner summon monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/#TOC-Summon-Monster-I-Sp-)

> Drawing on this ability uses up the same power that the summoner uses to call his eidolon.

Can a summoner use the spell [summon eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-eidolon) to have the eidolon out and use their summon ability? I believe that its only the ritual to summon the eidolon counts and not the spell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

> Treat this as if you had summoned your eidolon normally, except that it only remains with you for the duration of this spell.

During Summon Eidolon's duration, it is as if you have summoned your eidolon naturally, so you can not use your Summon Monster class ability.

Comment: But I could have the Eidolon out and use regular summon monster spells?

Comment: Yes of course, that’s what your other quetion asks.